# How to pass a mixin reference into another mixin as a mixin parameter in jade4j

Tags: pug, mixins, jade4j

What I want to achieve is as follows in jade4j -

```
mixin mixin_a()
  p This is mixin A

mixin mixin_b(mixin_reference)
  p This is mixin B
    +mixin_reference()

+mixin_b(mixin_a)
```

Here I am passing mixin_a as a reference in `mixin_b` and expecting that as a parameter.

But, when I try to do `+mixin_reference()` it says - `mixin_reference is not defined`.

Question:
1. What wrong I am doing in calling the mixin_reference?
2. What should be the best to achieve the same functionality? (reason is this, because I am expecting passed parameter mixin name in `mixin_b` as dynamic value.

Answer (score 0):

Since Jade v1.0.0 this is possible:

```
mixin mixin_a
  p Yeah, mixin A!

mixin mixin_b(mixMeIn)
  p Yeah, mixin B!
  +#{mixMeIn}  

+mixin_b('mixin_a')
```

Comment: It works for jade (for js) but doesn't work for jade4j (jade for Java), which was the actual question...